# Limit precision on JSONEncoder's Double output

Tags: json, swift, jsonencoder

I'm working on a document-based SwiftUI application, and my file contents includes large arrays of doubles. The application involves importing some data from CSV, and then the file saves this data in a data structure.

However, when looking at the file sizes, the custom document type I declare in my application is 2-3 times larger than the CSV file. The other bits of metadata could not possibly be that large.

Here's the JSON output that is saved to file:

[image: JSON output saved to file]

Here's the CSV file that was imported:

[image: original CSV file]

On looking at the raw text of the JSON output and comparing it with the original CSV, it became obvious that the file format I declare was using a lot of unnecessary precision. How do I make Swift's JSONEncoder only use, for example, 4 decimal places of precision?

Comment: You could use `Decimal` instead of `Double` as the data type, or use a custom encode. `JSONEncoder` has no option for precision.

Comment: Or use strings in your json

Comment: You could customize the encoding behaviour using a property wrapper. Every time you write a double to the property, you could have it round in a way that shorts it’s decimal representation. Not sure about how to do that exactly, though